# DESC Sorting with NULLS LAST?

Tags: php, sorting, yii2

How can I set default DESC sorting with puting NULLS on botton of my list? Theres part of my code which is responsible for sorting:

```
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder = ['created_at' => SORT_DESC];
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['created_at'] = [
    'asc' => [Production::tableName().'.created_at' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => [Production::tableName().'.created_at' => SORT_DESC]
];
```

Regards

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['created_at'] = [
    'asc' => [new Expression(Production::tableName().'.created_at ASC NULLS FIRST')],
    'desc' => [new Expression(Production::tableName().'.created_at DESC NULLS LAST')]
];
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder = ['created_at' => SORT_DESC];
```

Comment: You forgot to close brackets at the end of new Expression value, but after adding it works great :)